# How can I manipulate textContent of a p element from inside a for-loop?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add textContent of a p element from inside a for-loop :

```js
const ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
const p = document.createElement('p')
p.classList.add('text-body-secondary')
for (let i = 0; i > ls.length; i++) {
  p.textContent += 'abc'
  // p.textContent = 'abc'   // Does not work either.
  if (i !== ls.length - 1) {
    p.textContent += ', '
  }
}
console.log(p)
```

expecting :

```js
<p class="text-body-secondary">abc, abc, abc, abc, abc, abc</p>
```

But it did not work.

Here are what I have tried:

- I have changed `const` to `let`.
- `p.textContent = 'abc'`
- no `forEach` or `map` since I need to use index.

Is this not allowed to manipulate p.textContent from inside a for-loop?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You are dealing with the DOM, so the text is made through a text-node: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp

Comment: have a look at the condition of the for loop. It never fires....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error:
`for (let i = 0; i > ls.length; i++)`

Correction:
`for (let i = 0; i < ls.length; i++)`

**`i` is less then `length`**

```js
const ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const p = document.createElement('p');
p.classList.add('text-body-secondary');

for (let i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
  p.textContent += 'abc';
  if (i !== ls.length - 1) {
    p.textContent += ', ';
  }
}
console.log(p);
```

Answer (score 2):

You for loop is going downwards, it should go upwards (should be `i < ls.length` not `i > ls.length`):

```js
const ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
const p = document.createElement('p')
p.classList.add('text-body-secondary')
for (let i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
  p.textContent += 'abc'
  // p.textContent = 'abc'   // Does not work either.
  if (i !== ls.length - 1) {
    p.textContent += ', '
  }
}
console.log(p)
```

Comment: Should be closed as a typo.

Comment: Should I delete this post or is 'closing' something different from deleting?

Answer (score 2):

You did a mistake: your loop was wrongly expecting `i > ls.length` which is false from beginning (correct one is `i < ls.length`)

```js
const ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
const p = document.createElement('p')
p.classList.add('text-body-secondary')
for (let i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
  p.textContent += 'abc'
  if (i < ls.length - 1) {
    p.textContent += ', '
  }
}
console.log(p)
```

I hope it suits your needs.